# No module named "flask" found, despite installation and activation

Tags: python, pip

My computer cannot find the flask module when I try to run it in my virtual environment. I am operating on Windows 10.

1. I have made sure that flask was installed in the virtual environment (blockchain-env/scripts/flask.exe).
2. I have made sure to activate my virtual environment.
3. I believe are no code errors in my __ init __.py file that I am trying to call from backend/app.

Any clue what's going on?

Comment: What does pip3 show Flask say?

Comment: Two things I would try would be to run those commands again from CLI instead of within Git Bash, and to delete and recreate the venv containing Flask.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're referencing the wrong instance of python on the device.

Run `which python3` and it will probably show that it's calling python from /usr/bin or somewhere similar.

Try running `python -m backend.app` to solve your problem

Comment: @Shyann, do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you"', instead, if it worked please mark this answer as the accepted one. Please have a look on what to do here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers